# Excel Formula | Count all values that have the "keyword" in the adjacent cell in the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This will be my first question on stackoverflow, I have done as much researching via google and this site but nothing I found relatable to this particular example. I attempted SUMIFS, VLOOKUP, etc.

This excel sheet will serve as donation tracker, each person will have their own row that goes from Jan-Dec. 1st sheet will serve as a tracker for the year, and the second sheet is where I want to the formula to tell me how much that person contributed via the 4 payment methods: Check, Cash, PayPal, and Facebook.

I'm having a hard time getting excel the formula to count the value for each type of payment in the row.

Here are snippets of my 2 sheets:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would use sumifs(), show you attempt and we may be able to sort it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a different format.  There is no easy formula that will work with your current format.  Sumif won't work with your format because the donation criteria is in the same row/column as the donation amount.

[Example Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxl43.png)

Sheet 1 would be as follows: Column A-Month, Column B-Name, Column C-Donation Type, and Column D-Donation Amount.  Column B is redundant, but is necessary with Sumifs.  Sumifs allows you to have multiple criteria, but both criteria have to be the same size adjacent to the row/column you are summing.  Column B can be hidden for a cleaner looking spreadsheet.  Columns F-H represent sheet 2.

The formula in G2 is as follows: =sumifs(D:D,B:B,F2,C:C,G1)

Comment: Not just Answering the Question but Suggesting a Good mechanism to solve a problem, This thing i like the most...:)

Comment: Thank you Josh, I will try the format you showed and try to come up with something! Appreciate your insight and help.